# Tengo un problema en vscode con github

Tags: vscode

Al abrir VSCODE, en la terminal de salida, me aparece esto, y no se porque me pasa, lo quiero quitar pero no se como, alguien me puede ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es usar la terminal, debes seleccionar el tab "Terminal".

Comment: No quiero que no se ejecute esos comandos cada vez, que abro vscode

Comment: No es un problema de git, github o de push.... voy a eliminar esas etiquetas.

Comment: Tendrás puestos esos comandos en un archivo como `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que eso no lo puedes quitar, VSCode es también un cliente de git y al arrancar hará sus comprobaciones y configuraciones, de hecho si te quedas mirando la salida, tira comandos cada cierto tiempo. Y cada funcionalidad de VSCode también tira sus comandos, yo no las miro nunca.
Si quieres ver la salida de Git limpia, te recomendaría ejecutar los comandos a mano en un terminal aparte y no a través de VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Esa salida es un "log" de comandos de [`git`](https://git-scm.com/), Visual Studio Code, por defecto trae activada la integración con esta herramienta. Entre otras cosas, cuando abres una carpeta mininamente se hacen verificaciones para saber si la misma forma parte de un repositorio `git`. No hay nada de malo en esto, aunque es cierto que hay una penalización pequeña en performance, que en tu caso pareciera estar muy por debajo del segundo. Mi sugerencia es convivir con esto, pero por supuesto puedes deshabilitar la integración con `git`:

- Ir a configuración <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>
- Ir a Extensiones -> Git
- Buscar el "checkbox" para deshabilitar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]